# How to create a new model object when a user signs up using django all-auth?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-allauth

When a user registers, I want to create a `profile` object like this: `profile = Profile.objects.create(username=username, points=0, age=0)`.
Django all-auth's register view looks like this:

```
class SignupView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, CloseableSignupMixin,
                 AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "account/signup." + app_settings.TEMPLATE_EXTENSION
    form_class = SignupForm
    redirect_field_name = "next"
    success_url = '/'

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_class(self):
        return get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, 'signup', self.form_class)

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Explicitly passed ?next= URL takes precedence
        ret = (
            get_next_redirect_url(
                self.request,
                self.redirect_field_name) or self.success_url)
        return ret

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # By assigning the User to a property on the view, we allow subclasses
        # of SignupView to access the newly created User instance
        self.user = form.save(self.request)
        try:
            return complete_signup(
                self.request, self.user,
                app_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION,
                self.get_success_url())
        except ImmediateHttpResponse as e:
            return e.response

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(SignupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = ret['form']
        email = self.request.session.get('account_verified_email')
        email_keys = ['email']
        if app_settings.SIGNUP_EMAIL_ENTER_TWICE:
            email_keys.append('email2')
        for email_key in email_keys:
            form.fields[email_key].initial = email
        login_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                                  reverse("account_login"),
                                                  self.redirect_field_name)
        redirect_field_name = self.redirect_field_name
        redirect_field_value = get_request_param(self.request,
                                                 redirect_field_name)
        ret.update({"login_url": login_url,
                    "redirect_field_name": redirect_field_name,
                    "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value})
        return ret
```

Where in this view would I write my object.create code? I find it abit hard to follow how all-auth's code is working hence why i'm asking. Here is my model if you're wondering:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='AnonymousUser')
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to listen for the [user_signed_up](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html) signal

```
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(user_signed_up)
def after_user_signed_up(request, user):

    profile = Profile.objects.create(username=user.username, points=0, age=0)
```

And your model is wrong. You should not be saving the username as a char field in your profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: I need `username` as CharField so when I click on another user's username in the comments or whatever, via AJAX it opens it easily by just getting the HTML of the username clicked, then doing `profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)`. Though I probably will eventually change it like you suggest, is it necessary if the model/field isn't related to security? As I said I can just .get() any profile by searching the CharField().

Comment: Also I tried your code, but I'm not too familiar with 'signals'. Would that function go under the `@sensitive_post_parameters_m` in the `SignupView`? Also i'm keeping my `username` as a Charfield for now, so would it just be `profile = Profile.objects.create(username=str(user.username), points=0, age=0)`?

Comment: The code can go in your views.py or models.py but you don't need he @sensitive_post_parameters decorator.

Comment: as for username charfield, you are practically kicking away all the functionality given to you by the django foreignkey field. Please take a moment to read up on it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do it now but having trouble with the transition. Could you have a look at my edit? It shows how my current CharField() is being used to assist in an ajax call. Could you tell me how I could transform my current process to ForeignKey()? If not i'll ask a seperate question.

Comment: Don't edit this question please. Ask another question saying you are trying to do this change. You can also ask if there are any real benefits in doing so. You can point to this question and say you got the idea from a suggestion here

Comment: I tried your initial answer `@receiver(user_signed_up)
def after_user_signed_up(request, user, **kwargs):
    profile = Profile.objects.create(username=user.username)
    profile.save()`. When I create a new account it gives an error `TypeError: 'username' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. Any idea?

Comment: sorry that should be Profile.objects.create(user=user.username)

Comment: Now it's giving a `ValueError: Cannot assign "'newuser123'": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance.`

Comment: sorry having one of those days `Profile.objects.create(user=user, ...)